# How do i put command work for my id and my friend id eg. when i tried this it worked with my friend id only

Tags: discord.js

The code:

```js
client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.author.id !== "my id") || message.author.id !== "my friend id") return message.delete();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should format your code, secondly, here is the code you should use:

```js
client.on('message', msg => {
  if(msg.author.id === 'id' || msg.author.id === 'id') {
    //code to run
  } else {
    return msg.delete();
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use array:

```
let users = ['your id', 'your friend's id'];
if(users.includes(message.author.id)){
// your code goes here

} 
else {
return msg.delete();
}
```

Comment: *message.delete()